# DrawString - unwanted vertical offset in some fonts

Tags: c#, graphics, fonts

I'm drawing some texts on a graphic object. With some fonts drawn text has some unwanted vertical offset.

Here is the code:

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
Graphics GraphicObject = Graphics.FromImage(img);
GraphicObject.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
GraphicObject.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, X, Y, Width, Height);
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip;

GraphicObject.DrawString(
     "SampleText",
     new FontFamily("Font_Name"),
     Color.White,
     new RectangleF(X, Y, Width, Height),
     format
);
```

And here is the result:
[image]

As you see, position of two fonts are wrong

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide some working code snippet so people can test it.

Comment: Not sure if that is really wrong; if you look closer you will see that example four also lets the descenders go below the rectangle. I guess it all depends on how the fonts is defining its properties.. - Also: Do try out the much improved way to draw text with [TextRenderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!!

Comment: @tia : Code snippet Updated.

@TaW : It is natural that if a text can't fit in the rectangle then it get out of the box(`StringFormatFlags.NoClip`). My problem is the text offset from top of the rectangle!

Comment: I tried `TextRenderer` too and all `TextFormatFlags` tested, but it didn't fix the problem!

Comment: I can't reproduce with the fonts I have. I suspect it has to do with the details of the fonts you use. What fonts are they?

Comment: try this one: http://webexer.ir/W_amir.ttf

Comment: Works just as well here: [Screenshot](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10830831/FFF548.png.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hard works, I fixed the problem with a little dirty solution.

First I draw text on an empty `Graphics` object. then I'll scan for first pixel of text in y axis. This point is the y offset of font. Then I'll draw the text in my `Graphics` object at `y - yOffset`

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
Graphics GraphicObject = Graphics.FromImage(img);
GraphicObject.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
GraphicObject.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, X, Y, layer.Width, layer.Height);
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip;

int yOffset = GetYOffset(layer.Width,layer.Height,TextFont,layer.Text, format);

GraphicObject.DrawString(
     "SampleText",
     new FontFamily("Font_Name"),
     Color.White,
     new RectangleF(X, Y - yOffset, layer.Width, layer.Height),
     format
);

...

private int GetYOffset(int Width, int Height, System.Drawing.Font TextFont, string Text, StringFormat format)
{
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
    Graphics testGaraphic = null;
    testGaraphic = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    testGaraphic.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, Width, Height);
    testGaraphic.DrawString(Text, TextFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0, format);
    for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            if (img.GetPixel(x, y).Name != "ffffffff")
                return y;
    return 0;
}
```

The Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution above by Ali Gonabadi saved my day. I made some modification in order to be more precise in case of anti-aliasing text. Below is the function I adapted to get X offset coordinate with a couple of modifications related to the size of the Bitmap and the SmoothingMode:

```
private int GetXOffset(int Width, int Height, System.Drawing.Font TextFont, string Text, StringFormat format)
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);

    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, Width, Height);
    g.DrawString(Text, TextFont, Brushes.White, 0, 0, format);
    for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            if (image.GetPixel(x, y).Name != "ff000000")
                return x;
    return 0;
}
```